# Guava EventBus+Hazelcast Spring config

Tags: spring, hazelcast, event-bus

I have a requirement to display notification to user(Web page) as and when event occurs on server end .For example when message is received from queue I listen it to through spring JMS and need to pass it on to web page.

1.I chose hazelcast to send messages as my application is distributed across nodes and all nodes need to be informed. Is there any best approach other than this

2.How to use hazelcast to send messages to all nodes

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your case is a good fit for Hazelcast Topic. Please check the Hazelcast documentation at;

http://hazelcast.org/use-cases/messaging/ and
http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.6/manual/html-single/index.html#topic